# How to add a table (change data model) to the EF4 Context without lose of data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, dbcontext

I have an MVC3 project I created using the Code First paradigm and it works. I created a model inheriting from DBContext, and I can write to the table and all that. I need to add new table and change my model and I using  `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<T>` But, I lose all my data, due to EF4 will drop end create new DB.

```
public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges< MyDb >
```

Can I use different interface like `UpdateDatabaseIfModelChanges<T>` if any exist?

My model looks like this:

```
[Table("Person")]

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}

public class MyDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Then I call:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInitializer ());


public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges< MyDb >

    {
        protected override void Seed(MyDb context)
```

And this I want to create:

```
[Table("Person")]

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}
[Table("NewTable")]

public class NewTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}


public class MyDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet< NewTable > NewTable { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime" and "dynamically"? Your question doesn't provide any further details expected from your question's title. What I see in the question is static update expecting database update when you run the application next time because you have added a new class which requires recompilation.

Comment: I need to change database model without database drop, or copy old data to the new dabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Code first migrations and [EF 4.3 beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-released.aspx) where database upgrade is supported with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer. No RTM version support this yet.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, will process your link today, tomorrow.